# How much overhead does Monodroid add to an app

Tags: xamarin.android

Monodroid (and Monotouch) look like a great way to develop at least the non-ui part of an app cross-platform and use a common language.

However how much overhead does monodroid add for app size and CPU usage?

On the trial (emulator only) download it seems to install 27Mb of Mono, plus 12Mb of platform support but the faq says only ~4.4Mb will be added to an app in the final appstore?.

For running does Mono run a CLR VM in a Dalvik VM (i.e. is there any significant CPU overhead for something like writing games)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make debugging quicker, MonoDroid installs the Mono runtime and full set of class libraries to the device instead of packaging and transferring them with your application code every time you make a change.

When you change your project to Release mode, the Mono runtime and the class assemblies your application *actually uses* are placed in the apk.  Additional, a linker pass is run to remove classes and methods from those assemblies that your application does not use.

As the FAQ says, the current overhead is ~4.4MB.

The CLR VM runs separate from the Dalvik VM. (You can run native C code on Android.)  The 2 interact any time you use something in the Mono.Android namespace.

Comment: Do you know how the runtime speed is affected. Debugging a monodroid app appears a lot slower than a Java one but that could be many things.  I can't test on an actual without shelling out the money to try it. (Would be cool if it would deploy to a real device in some form of trial or restricted mode to test this)